# Stop animating of a SVG file - Code snippet included

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using a `SVG` image and animating the path of a diagram. It works fine. However, Once the image has been drawn I need to stop the iteration (stop from the image being redrawn). The code is found in this CODEPEN snippet attached [here](http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/FcxuL).

I tried removing `infinite` from `animation` in the `CSS` file, but the drawn image is being removed.

What I want to do is:

1.) Animate the image as shown in the code.

2.) Stop the animation from reanimating (this is because of the `infinite` attribute used in the `animation`)

3.) Once the image has been drawn, the image should remain the same unless the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
animation: draw 10s infinite linear;
```

to this:

```
animation: draw 10s forwards;
```

The forwards fill mode works as follows: After the animation ends (determined by animation-iteration-count), the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended